# How to update integer primary key adding 1000?

Tags: mysql

I have the following primary keys in my table: 1,2,3,4,5...

Is it possible to update these keys to: 1001,1002,1003,1004,1005... ?

```
UPDATE mytable SET `id`= (select `id` from mytable where id=??)+1000
```

Comment: Why do you need to select from another table? Surely `update mytable set id=id+1000` would be sufficient? Or do you have foreign keys pointing to this table?

Comment: Oops, I made a wrong copy-paste.

Comment: It is possible, but it can be a **very bad idea**: unless you update all related foreign keys pointing to this Id, you can break things badly

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that, however if you need to do this regularly, then something is probably bad in your DB or software design.

The purpose of the primary keys is to identify the records. They should not have any additional information. This rule may be stepped over on the some optimization reasons, or in special cases (like DB merge, refactor) but that is all.

Furthermore, typically the primary keys are referred by external parts of your software (either by foreign keys from other tables, or by non-db parts of your software). Be careful, changing a primary key requires to change it everywhere where they are referred. The `CASCADE` parameter of the foreign keys may help a lot, if you are using MySQL.

Put this additional information in alternate columns, you will spare a lot of pain on the longterm with that.

Comment: You forget about "merge DB" while id's values intersects. In another cases you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Akine Right, I improved the post.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET id = id + 1000
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I think the `ORDER BY` is not very needed, or is it?

Comment: @peterh, It is in MySQL in some situations

Comment: @peterh, see:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and search for "If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, " on the page

Comment: @Lennart Wow, thank you! It is useful to know.

Comment: @peterh No, ORDER BY is **critically** needed to avoid unique constraint violation.